# Swift 3: Unrecognized selector sent to instance Xcode 8

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uigesturerecognizer

I have programmatically created an `UIView` and added `UIPanGestureRecognizer` to it:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController{
    var preludeView: UIView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        initViews()
        createConstrants()

        let panGestureRecognizer = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector(("handleTap:")))
        preludeView.addGestureRecognizer(panGestureRecognizer)
    }

    func handleTap(recognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
        print("WORKING!!!!")
    }

    func initViews() {
        ...
    }

    func createConstrants() {
        ...
    }
}
```

But when I am touching the view Xcode is throwing an error:

> 2016-07-13 09:24:29.918 Draft_Hypa_02[661:83024]
>   -[Draft_Hypa_02.ViewController handleTap:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x17d94a10 2016-07-13 09:24:29.921
>   Draft_Hypa_02[661:83024] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Draft_Hypa_02.ViewController
>   handleTap:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x17d94a10'
>   *** First throw call stack: (0x249cf91b 0x2416ae17 0x249d52b5 0x249d2ee1 0x248fe238 0x294ae9eb 0x290e984f 0x28f7aff1 0x294afd4f
>   0x28f3ba57 0x28f38017 0x28f78ec9 0x28f7867b 0x28f49125 0x28f476d3
>   0x24991dff 0x249919ed 0x2498fd5b 0x248df229 0x248df015 0x25ecfac9
>   0x28fb1189 0x93144 0x24587873) libc++abi.dylib: terminating with
>   uncaught exception of type NSException

However, if I remove argument in the `handleTap` function and remove the colon in the `Selector(("handleTap:"))`, everything works fine!

Already spent a day to try to fix this issue and would be very appreciate for your help!

Answer (score 30, accepted):

If you are using `swift` 3 your `selector` should be  like this

```
#selector(self.handleTap(recognizer:))
```

Comment: Xcode is throwing "Value of type 'ViewController' has no member 'handleTap'"

Comment: @Forze you need also to add an underscore before the method first parameter. `func handleTap(_ recognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {`

Comment: @Nirav thanks, It works! Do you know in Swift 3 we must set external name for action function?

Comment: Yes in swift 3 to call the first parameter you must write parameter name, you can check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38343765/6433023) for more info

Comment: @LeoDabus, you comment helped me a lot!

Answer (score 6):

You should write this statement in different way.
use following line

> let panGestureRecognizer = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self,
>   action: #selector(ViewController.handleTap(_:)))

instead of

> let panGestureRecognizer = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self,
>   action: Selector(("handleTap:")))

New Way

> let panGestureRecognizer = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self,
>   action: #selector(YourViewController.handleTap(_:)))

Comment: Xcode 8 is throwing "Value of type 'ViewController' has no member 'handleTap'"

Comment: use self instead of ViewController or name of your viewController

Comment: @Forze:  handleTap is name of method, You are calling

func handleTap(sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer){}

Comment: @Mahendre I used self and its still giving the same error

Comment: @Markinson Can you post your function and its calling syntax

Comment: @Mahendre Y I figured it out. Your code was right. I just forgot to write the name of my .swift file before calling the func

Answer (score 2):

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let customView = UIView()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let panGestureRecognizer = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleTap(_:)))
        customView.addGestureRecognizer(panGestureRecognizer)
    }

    func handleTap(panGesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {

    }
}
```

Don't forget to add your custom UIView to the VC.

Comment: I am adding UIView in initViews() and put this function in the viewDidLoad()