# Unrecognized selector sent to instance when clicking on UITextField

Tags: ios, swift, selector, nsnotification

I'm having trouble with the following error:

```
[UTK_Math_Recruiting.FirstViewController keyboardWillHide:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f824140f230
2016-12-08 11:01:57.696 UTK Math Recruiting[5844:333433] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UTK_Math_Recruiting.FirstViewController keyboardWillHide:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f824140f230'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010e41634b __exceptionPreprocess + 171
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010ae6b21e objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010e485f34 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 132
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010e39bc15 ___forwarding___ + 1013
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010e39b798 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010e3b419c __CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER__ + 12
    6   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010e3b409b _CFXRegistrationPost + 427
    7   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010e3b3e02 ___CFXNotificationPost_block_invoke + 50
    8   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010e376ea2 -[_CFXNotificationRegistrar find:object:observer:enumerator:] + 2018
    9   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010e375f3b _CFXNotificationPost + 667
    10  Foundation                          0x000000010a9330ab -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 66
    11  UIKit                               0x000000010c672c4e -[UIInputWindowController postStartNotifications:withInfo:] + 378
    12  UIKit                               0x000000010c674eef __77-[UIInputWindowController moveFromPlacement:toPlacement:starting:completion:]_block_invoke.871 + 382
    13  UIKit                               0x000000010bcb3a6d +[UIView(UIViewAnimationWithBlocks) _setupAnimationWithDuration:delay:view:options:factory:animations:start:animationStateGenerator:completion:] + 581
    14  UIKit                               0x000000010bcb3ee8 +[UIView(UIViewAnimationWithBlocks) _animateWithDuration:delay:options:animations:start:completion:] + 119
    15  UIKit                               0x000000010c67491c -[UIInputWindowController moveFromPlacement:toPlacement:starting:completion:] + 1627
    16  UIKit                               0x000000010c67ce59 __43-[UIInputWindowController setInputViewSet:]_block_invoke.1316 + 98
    17  UIKit                               0x000000010c67029a -[UIInputWindowController performOperations:withTemplateNotificationInfo:] + 46
    18  UIKit                               0x000000010c67c9e2 -[UIInputWindowController setInputViewSet:] + 1923
    19  UIKit                               0x000000010c673f30 -[UIInputWindowController performOperations:withAnimationStyle:] + 50
    20  UIKit                               0x000000010c2ea24f -[UIPeripheralHost(UIKitInternal) setInputViews:animationStyle:] + 1432
    21  UIKit                               0x000000010be11041 -[UIResponder _finishResignFirstResponder] + 267
    22  UIKit                               0x000000010c70e4e6 -[UITextField _finishResignFirstResponder] + 49
    23  UIKit                               0x000000010be11103 -[UIResponder resignFirstResponder] + 140
    24  UIKit                               0x000000010c70e3b5 -[UITextField resignFirstResponder] + 136
    25  UIKit                               0x000000010bca7703 -[UIView(Hierarchy) _removeFirstResponderFromSubtree] + 167
    26  UIKit                               0x000000010bca7d82 __UIViewWillBeRemovedFromSuperview + 76
    27  UIKit                               0x000000010bca7b3e -[UIView(Hierarchy) removeFromSuperview] + 95
    28  UIKit                               0x000000010bd72a86 -[UITransitionView _didCompleteTransition:] + 874
    29  UIKit                               0x000000010bd740cb -[UITransitionView transition:fromView:toView:removeFromView:] + 3851
    30  UIKit                               0x000000010bd731a8 -[UITransitionView transition:fromView:toView:] + 63
    31  UIKit                               0x000000010bd72ee3 -[UITransitionView transition:toView:] + 153
    32  UIKit                               0x000000010bdf985d -[UITabBarController transitionFromViewController:toViewController:transition:shouldSetSelected:] + 1889
    33  UIKit                               0x000000010bdf8721 -[UITabBarController transitionFromViewController:toViewController:] + 59
    34  UIKit                               0x000000010bdf45e2 -[UITabBarController _setSelectedViewController:] + 365
    35  UIKit                               0x000000010bdf4464 -[UITabBarController setSelectedViewController:] + 234
    36  UIKit                               0x000000010bdf85ce -[UITabBarController _tabBarItemClicked:] + 369
    37  UIKit                               0x000000010bbfb5b8 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 83
    38  UIKit                               0x000000010c013c72 -[UITabBar _sendAction:withEvent:] + 579
    39  UIKit                               0x000000010bbfb5b8 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 83
    40  UIKit                               0x000000010bd80edd -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 67
    41  UIKit                               0x000000010bd811f6 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 444
    42  UIKit                               0x000000010c0163fa -[UITabBar _buttonUp:] + 113
    43  UIKit                               0x000000010bbfb5b8 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 83
    44  UIKit                               0x000000010bd80edd -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 67
    45  UIKit                               0x000000010bd811f6 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 444
    46  UIKit                               0x000000010bd800f2 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 668
    47  UIKit                               0x000000010bc68ce1 -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 2747
    48  UIKit                               0x000000010bc6a3cf -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 4011
    49  UIKit                               0x000000010bc1763f -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 371
    50  UIKit                               0x000000010c40971d __dispatchPreprocessedEventFromEventQueue + 3248
    51  UIKit                               0x000000010c4023c7 __handleEventQueue + 4879
    52  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010e3bb311 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
    53  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010e3a059c __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 556
    54  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010e39fa86 __CFRunLoopRun + 918
    55  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010e39f494 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 420
    56  GraphicsServices                    0x0000000111c3da6f GSEventRunModal + 161
    57  UIKit                               0x000000010bbf9964 UIApplicationMain + 159
    58  UTK Math Recruiting                 0x000000010a7f635f main + 111
    59  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010f34368d start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Here is the code I use:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                           selector: Selector(("keyboardWillShow:")),
                                           name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow,
                                           object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                           selector: Selector(("keyboardWillHide:")),
                                           name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide,
                                           object: nil)
}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
}

func keyboardWillShow(note: NSNotification) {
    if let keyboardSize = (note.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
        var frame = tableView.frame
        UIView.beginAnimations(nil, context: nil)
        UIView.setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState(true)
        UIView.setAnimationDuration(0.3)
        frame.size.height -= keyboardSize.height
        tableView.frame = frame
        if activeTextField != nil {
            let rect = tableView.convert((activeTextField?.bounds)!, from: activeTextField)
            tableView.scrollRectToVisible(rect, animated: false)
        }
        UIView.commitAnimations()
    }
}

func keyboardWillHide(note: NSNotification) {
    if let keyboardSize = (note.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
        var frame = tableView.frame
        UIView.beginAnimations(nil, context: nil)
        UIView.setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState(true)
        UIView.setAnimationDuration(0.3)
        frame.size.height += keyboardSize.height
        tableView.frame = frame
        UIView.commitAnimations()
    }
}
```

When the app launches it launches into the `FirstViewController`. `FirstViewController` can display a form of custom `UITableViewCell's` which has to be loaded from the `SecondViewController`. When a form is loaded and I click on a `UITextField` as if to fill it out with information the app crashes with the above error. I can not figure out this error, also it only seems to throw the error for `keyboardWillHide`.

Comment: Change your `Notification` observer selector like this http://stackoverflow.com/a/38344318/6433023

Comment: So I need to switch this to a UIPanGestureRecognizer?? Did it really change that much in the new version of swift?

Comment: I have told you to change your selector syntax like that answer of my, something like `#selector(self.keyboardWillHide(note:))` and `#selector(self.keyboardWillShow(note:))`

Comment: It throws an error if you modify only that part of the observer, as I was implying.

Comment: Have you try like my above comment,

Comment: @AlexCauthen Nirav means change the `Selector(("..."))` to `#selector(...)` when you call `addObserver`.

Comment: Sorry that was not clear. That does work. However, the keyboard that appears is completely blank and only appears once, so something else is going horribly wrong.