# How to use an IBAction to write data to Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, gmsplace

I'm having trouble figuring out how to write data to my Firebase Database through an IBAction.

My problem is not being able to write to the actual database, it's the type of data that is being written.

I need to write data using a Google Maps Services Place object. Here's my database write code:

```
let newWaitTime = Int(waitTimeLabel.text!)

let waitTime = databaseRef.child("times").child(place.placeID).childByAutoId()

waitTime.setValue(newWaitTime)
```

The problem is since `IBAction` functions aren't able to take other parameters, I can't pass my `place` variable into the function in order to allow me to write to my database.

I can't seem to figure out a workaround because it requires knowing the `place.placeID` to submit the times. Without that there is no way to distinguish which times belong to which places. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the main class add the following

```
var currentPlace: Place?
```

then whenever you are interacting with a certain place

```
self.currentPlace = placeImInteractingWith
```

in the IBAction

```
if let placeToUse = currentPlace {
    let waitTime = databaseRef.child("times").child(placeToUse.placeID).childByAutoId()
    //etc
{
```

Comment: Even with that, I still get the following error `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Crunch_Time_Real.cardView submitButtonPressed:place:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x102152eb0'
***`

Comment: This is unrelated to firebase

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38344184/swift-3-unrecognized-selector-sent-to-instance-xcode-8