# Swift 3: Why symbol _ is added before sender in parameters of action?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3

My Xcode has been recently updated to Xcode 8 with Swift 3. What I have noticed is that when attaching actions to ViewController functions are generated in this style:

```
@IBAction func methodName(_ sender: UIButton) {

}
```

I don't understand what is the purpose of having `_` there. Could anyone explain why it is there? In previous Swift 2.2 it was not there.

Another question is that previous project I have done by watching tutorial has migrated to Swift 3, and there was one method which looked like this:

```
func toggleButtons(toggle: Bool) {
    yesButton.isUserInteractionEnabled = toggle
    noButton.isUserInteractionEnabled = toggle
}
```

I was calling this method like this: `toggleButtons(false)` still not passing the argument name. Now migrator has changed it as below but nothing was changed in calling of method later in code.

```
func toggleButtons(_ toggle: Bool) {
    yesButton.isUserInteractionEnabled = toggle
    noButton.isUserInteractionEnabled = toggle
}
```

Is it a different situation from the previous case?

Comment: This is not a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38343497/swift-3-first-parameter-names because that question is about the change in first parameter name between Swift 2 and Swift 3, while this question is about **why** Xcode disables the parameter name when it generates an `@IBAction` method.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The other answers (one of which has been deleted) covered what the `_` means: it eliminates the keyword when you call the method.

However, your question is specifically about “attaching actions to ViewController”.

Methods that have the `@IBAction` attribute can be connected to controls in your storyboard (or xib). That means the name of the method will be stored, as a string, in the storyboard, and it will be called using the Objective-C message sending system. So the exact name, and how the name is translated to Objective-C, matters very much here.

If you declare the method `func methodName(sender: UIButton)`, then its Objective-C name is `methodNameWithSender:`.

If you declare the method `func methodName(_ sender: UIButton)`, then its Objective-C name is `methodName:`.

Both iOS and macOS have something called the “responder chain”, which lets the system search for an object (a “responder”) that can handle an action. You can connect the controls in your storyboard to the First Responder (at the top of the document outline) to have the system do this. Most commonly you do this with menu items in macOS, but there are other uses.

Anyway, there are some standard actions like `cut:`, `copy:` and `paste:`. For example, you would set your Cut menu item's action to send `cut:` to First Responder. And if you want to implement the `cut:` method in your view controller, it is critical that its name (when translated to Objective-C) be precisely `cut:`, and not `cutWithSender:`. If it's named `cut:`, the system will find it when searching the responder chain, but if it's named `cutWithSender:`, the system will **not** find it and you will wonder why your menu item doesn't work.

Xcode knows this, so it always creates action methods of the form `@IBAction func action(_ sender: UIButton)`, omitting the keyword from the argument, in case you are implementing an action that needs to be found by searching the responder chain.

In Swift 3, every argument to a method has a keyword by default, including the first argument. Back in Swift 2, the first argument did **not** have a keyword by default, so the `_` on the first argument was redundant in Swift 2 (and would generate a compiler warning). That is why Xcode 8 (Swift 3) puts in the `_` but Xcode 7 (Swift 2.2) did not.

That is also why your `toggleButtons` example worked in Xcode 7.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I have updated my question. I would appreciate if you could help me to understand more about it. I've just started learning iOS.

Answer (score 2):

It means that you do not have to name the parameter when calling the method.

```
obj.methodName(button)

// no need for
obj.methodName(sender: button)
```

In earlier Swift versions, that was the special default behaviour for the first parameter in a method call, but in Swift3 that has been unified. All parameters now need names, unless you opt out (with the `_`).

Comment: Thanks for your help @Thilo !