# Tableview's delegate methods are not calling

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am trying to use tableview with delegate methods.

But it is not working.

My class:

```
class IsteklerTVVC: UITableViewController {

    @IBOutlet var mainTable: UITableView!
    let missionControl = MissionControl.sharedInstance
    var yardimList:[YardimIstek] = [YardimIstek]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        mainTable.delegate=self
        mainTable.dataSource=self
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        veriGetir()
    }

    func veriGetir() {
        let parameters: Parameters = [
            "uid": missionControl.id
        ]
        Alamofire.request("domain.com", method: .post, parameters: parameters).responseJSON { response in
            print("istek eklendi \(parameters)")
            let json = JSON(response.result.value)
            for (key,subJson):(String, JSON) in json {
                print(subJson[0]["tarih"].string)

                let blok=YardimIstek()
                blok.id=0
                blok.isim="Name"
                blok.tarih=subJson[0]["tarih"].string!
                blok.lat=subJson[0]["lat"].string!
                blok.long=subJson[0]["long"].string!
                self.yardimList.append(blok)
            }
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.mainTable.reloadData()
                print("ok \(self.yardimList.count)")
            }
        }
    }

    let textCellIdentifier = "mainCell"
    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return yardimList.count
    }
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell: isteklerCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: textCellIdentifier) as! isteklerCell
        let row = indexPath.row
        let blok=yardimList[row]

        cell.setCell(blok: blok)


        return cell
    }
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath as IndexPath, animated: true)
    }



}
class isteklerCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var isimSoyisim: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var zaman: UILabel!

    func setCell(blok: YardimIstek) {
        isimSoyisim.text=blok.isim
        zaman.text=blok.tarih
    }
}
```

The problem is, no delegate methods are getting called. I think there is a problem with names. Because when I was using Swift 2, I used the tableview's outlet name as "tableView" and it was working well. Now Swift 3 is not allowing that naming.

So my tableview is looking empty even there is data in `yardimList` dictionary.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: A `UITableViewController` already has a `tableView` property which is wired to itself. You don't have to create another one. Remove the `mainTable` property and use the default `tableView` one. If you are using a storyboard make sure your view controller is of the right type in the storyboard.

Comment: Please look at the Swift 3 documentation. Just about everything has been renamed from Swift 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your delegate function signatures are wrong. They were updated with swift 3:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int        
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
```

Comment: What does it mean "_" ?

Comment: It means the first parameter doesn't have to have the name before the value. Check [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39631054/4812253) for a better answer.

Comment: @to Let me know if that fix allows your delegate funcs to get called. If not we can keep troubleshooting

Comment: Than you so much i will try tomorrow and let u know

Answer (score 0):

Two things to check:

First one is do you need the `mainTable` property? UITableViewControllers comes with a UITableView property called `tableView`. If you don't need 'mainTable', you can just replace it with `tableView`.

Second, if you do need `mainTable`, then you need to make sure you connected the `@IBOutlet` to the `UITableView` you want to use.